# Spring boot application profile dependent data soruces

Tags: maven, spring-boot, configuration, profile

Ive currently an spring boot application that uses as data source in the application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@dev.example.org:1521:SID
```

The application can be build with different profiles, one for  the local development and one that can be used to deploy to an application server (weblogic). This works with following in the pom.xml Building without a profile let me deploy into the application server with the *dev.local* profile I can start it directly and debugg local.

```
   <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>dev.local</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                    <version>${spring-boot-version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
```

But me problem is that I would like to have as well different data sources used in the default and in the development profile.
In the default(production) profile I would like to use JNDI like:

```
spring.datasource.jndi-name=jdbc/datasourceName
```

I tried it with overwriting the application.properties - but this seems to be tedious and problematic as I would have to double the file and maintain it twice.

What would be the right way to solve this challenge?